# Using makeLens with Gloss gives "can't load framework: OpenGL (not found)"

Tags: haskell, gloss

```
System: Mac OS X Big Sur
ghc : 8.8.4
cabal: 3.2.0.0
```

I can install all gloss-examples and run without issues.

But when I use `makelens ''Foo`

It suddenly complains:

```
<command line>: can't load framework: OpenGL (not found)
```

I tried with `microlens` and same behavior.

Why?

Below are the codes I've used:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import           Control.Lens                       hiding (element)
import           Graphics.Gloss
import           Graphics.Gloss.Interface.Pure.Game


data ManGame = ManGame {
  mgPic :: Picture,
  mgX   :: Float,
  mgY   :: Float
  -- Add _mgKeyDown to have press and hold function
                       } deriving Show
--makeLenses ''ManGame
```

This works. But if I uncommented the last line, it reports error during compilation.

For the cabal file(I've used the same as with other gloss-examples programs):

```
Executable gloss-game
  Main-is:        Main.hs
  hs-source-dirs: picture/Game

  Build-depends:
          base                          >= 4.8 && < 5
        , lens
        , gloss                         == 1.13.*

  Default-Language:
        Haskell2010

  ghc-options:
        -O2
        -Wall
        -threaded
        -rtsopts
```

Comment: Does this error happen at compile time or at runtime?

Comment: Can you share some snippets and the cabal file? It seems like some external libraries are missing, but it is weird that the problem pops up when using leneses

Comment: @lsmor I've added some snippets and cabal file

Comment: @daydaynatation honestly, I don't know what's going on... have you tried to create lenses manually with `lens` function?. Just to discard TH as the source of problems

Comment: You might be experiencing [this recently fixed bug](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/issues/18446).  It still affects GHC 8.8.4.

Comment: I've just upgraded to ghc 8.10.2, seems that bug fix is not yet included